# Chamar um executável sem ser pelo Process em c#

Tags: c#, .net

Existe alguma forma de chamar um executável sem ser pelo processo?

Preciso de alguma coisa que não use o código abaixo para chamar um executável pois quando finalizo um processo de uma aplicação que não é nativa do Windows, não consigo chamá-la novamente com o comando:

```
foreach (Process pr in Process.GetProcessesByName(nomeExecutavel))
        {
            if (!pr.HasExited) 
    pr.Start();
        }
```

Obs.: É um console Application em C#

Comment: Podes explicar melhor o que pretendes fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode executar uma aplicação pelo caminho do executável:

```
Process.Start("c:\\caminho do executável.exe");
```

Comment: Preciso chamar uma aplicação WPF sem utilizar o Process.Start dentro de um console application. Dessa forma não funciona também

Comment: O que acontece quando você chama o executável da aplicação WPF usando o `Process.Start`? Dá exceção?

Comment: Ficou um pouco lento com o Process.Start mas funcionou.